# "post_per_page" not displaying the number of posts specified

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I have an issue with displaying the desired number of posts per page. I tried changing the number of specified posts 'post_per_page' => '3' but the result are still the same number of 4 posts. In the twig file I am just outputting the result with a simple loop statement: {% for project in projects %}

```html
$context = Timber::context();

$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'post_per_page' => '3'
);
$context['projects'] =  new Timber\Postquery($query);

$timber_post = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $timber_post;
Timber::render( array( 'pages/page-' . $timber_post->post_name . '.twig', 'pages/page.twig' ), $context );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `posts_per_page`, not post_per_page

Answer (score 0):

The right way : must be like `posts_per_page` args element.

Also you should use, `Timber::get_posts($query)` instead of `Timber\Postquery($query)`;

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `Timber::get_posts()` if you don’t need pagination. You only must use `Timber\PostQuery()` if you want to make it work with Timber’s pagination.

Comment: @Gchtr  posts per page not only using for pagination. you can use it for getting number of posts.

Comment: Yes, I know. Maybe I should have said: Nothing wrong with using `Timber\PostQuery()` in the use case of the question. If you just say that `Timber::get_post()` should be used instead of `Timber\PostQuery()` without saying why it’s better, then developers might think that `Timber::get_posts()` is better all the time. But it depends on the use case. Just wanted to clarify that :).